# How to pass PHP variable in PayPal JavaScript as payment amount

Tags: php, paypal, codeigniter-3

So I have this application which I am trying to implement [PayPal Express][1]

[1]: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client but my problem is I cannot be able to pick the price variable from php to javascript 'value'

I have tried `value: '<?php echo $order_amount;?>'` 
to no avail.

This is the PayPal JS:

```
<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

How do I call this `$order_amount` as the `value` in the js so that I can process the payment?

Comment: When you tried, how specifically did it fail?  Was there an error from PHP?  An error from JavaScript?  An unexpected result?

Comment: No error. But it is getting the wrong amount not the amount supplied by the variable. For instance, the variable amount that I have tried with is $21 but when you login to paypal it shows $600

Comment: What debugging have you done to confirm that it's outputting the value you expect?  When you output the value from PHP to your JavaScript code, when you examine that output in your browser's page source, what value was emitted to the client?  What is the exact resulting line of JavaScript code?

Comment: Upon debugging I am still getting order value as 600, which is wrong. This is because I have a default button which is calculating the value as 21. I have tried to figure out from my system where it is getting this figure with no luck.

Comment: *"Upon debugging I am still getting order value as 600"* - If this code: `value: '<?php echo $order_amount;?>'` is resulting in this output: `value: '600'` then the runtime value of `$order_amount` is `600`.  If that value is incorrect then you'll need to find where that value is coming from and why it isn't what you expect it to be.  The code shown has nothing to do with that.  Basically it sounds like the problem is elsewhere and not where you assume it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, thanks to @David's guidance.

I was failing to define the value id on PayPal's js.

Right at the top I created a hidden input field with an id like so:

`<input  type="hidden" id="t_amount" value="<?php echo $orders['order_amount']; ?>">`

This is what I added:

```
 var amountt= document.getElementById("t_amount").value; 
        console.log(amountt);
```

I then put `amountt` as the value and it worked like charm.

Here is my whole code:

```
<script>
        var amountt= document.getElementById("t_amount").value; 
        console.log(amountt);
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    
                    amount: {
                        value: amountt
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**I have solved this by doing this:**
paypal.Buttons({
    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: (data, actions) => {
    var amountt = document.getElementById("total_amount").value; 
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
            value: amountt // Can also reference a variable or function
}
}]
});
},
```